# How to install cakephp 3.1.6 on LAMP

Tags: php, ubuntu, cakephp, lamp, cakephp-3.x

I want to install cakephp3 on ubuntu14.0.4 in lamp. I put cakephp3 folder in `/var/www/` path. When I enter `localhost/cakephp3/`in browser, nothing is shown.

What should I do?

Comment: Shouldn't you also specify a port number: `localhost:XXXX`?

Comment: I do this but doesn't work. I think that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I have the full access to the cakephp folder.

Comment: Please can you check the error log ? mostly its located at /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: 127.0.0.1:58522] PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /var/www/html/cakephp-3-1-6/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error.log :

> 127.0.0.1:59267] PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /var/www/html/cakephp-3-1-6/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

So

install "intl" plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And Try again in browser: `localhost/cakephp3/`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this,
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp

open terminal,

1. Create a folder in var/www/html

   ```
   mkdir /var/www/html/cakephp3
   ```
2. Navigate to this folder and install composer there

   ```
   cd /var/www/html/cakephp3
   curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
   ```
3. Install php in the same folder

   ```
   php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app
   ```

You must get your cakephp application now.